# how to get xpath - selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I testautomated a small part of Outlook Web App. Here I check a test mailbox that our company sends emails to. Within a certain email there are texts I want to check by using Assert. The problem is that I have difficulties finding the right xpath. The HTML looks like this:

```
   <div align="left">
    <font size="2" face="Tahoma">
    <br>
        Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt.
    </font>
    <br>
   </div>
```

To use `driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))` I used the following xpath first:
`//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]/br`, but that gives me just the `<br>` tag.

Afther that I tried `//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]/text()` and that seemed to give me the xpath that I wanted, because in element inspector it highlighted the text *Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt*. That is the actual text that I want the selenium webdriver to find and use to store (with `.getText()`) in a String. But when I used that with `driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText()` it gave me a NoSuchElementException.

What did I do wrong? What would be the right xpath that I can use with the webdriver to get the text?

Comment: Can you open this webapp with chrome? It has powerful developer console functions like get xpath from element (right click on html element)

Comment: <br> is just a line break, it can not contain text content!

Comment: So with our without <br> does not work, I see that it is just a line break. But that still leaves //font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]/text()

Comment: Yes, I am using inspect element. I usually try to avoid copy xpath and make my own xpath since if you us copy xpath you get xpaths like these: //*[@id="Item.MessageUniqueBody"]/div/div/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/font/text(). If something changes in the HTML there will be a fair chance that my xpath cannot be reused either

Comment: @K2017, Can you write your syntax which you are using in your script ? With String, if you are retrieving in it.

Comment: What is the point of extracting text from node located by exactly the same text?

Comment: String tekstBouwdepotdeclaratie = selenium.searchForElementByLocatorWithoutSwitchToFrame("//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]/text()").getText();

Comment: the searchForElementByLocatorWithoutSwitchToFrame is a method that I often use to keep searching for a element for 30 seconds until the element is found

Comment: @Andersson, see JeffC' answer below. I adjusted my Assert on the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your HTML is set up and given what you want, you want to get the `FONT` tag. In your first XPath you are pulling the `BR` tag, which is why it didn't work. Your second XPath is using `text()` which, if I remember correctly, isn't supported by Selenium. The easier way is to modify your first XPath to just get the `FONT` tag (just remove `/br`).

```
//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]
```

Using this XPath, the code below should work.

```
String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText().trim();
```

I added `trim()` to remove the `BR` spacing and other possible whitespace. You can remove it if it's not needed/wanted.

---

Based on OP's feedback, I would use the XPath above but I would change the assert to

```
By locator = By.xpath("//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]");
List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(locator);
Assert.assertTrue(e.size() > 0, "Verify text exists in email");
```

Comment: As Andersson already pointed out, it seems strange that you want to locate an element given some text and then get the text contained in that element. You might want to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to validate if the contents of the email is what I expect. If I already know what I am expecting then I just need the contents of the email to compare in a Assert. Do you know a better way?

Comment: Thanks! I just adjusted it to e.size() == 1. Just to make sure that the same line is not shown more than once

Answer (score 0):

As you were able to figure out the *WebElement* through the *xpath* `//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]/text()` but through your script you are getting **NoSuchElementException** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be visible as follows :

```
String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_the_element"))).getText();
```

---

### Update

As you are getting *TimeoutException* as an alternative you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the parent element to be visible and use *Java Split* method to extract the desired text as follows :

```
String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]")));
String[] myTextParts = myText.split(Pattern.quote("<br>"));
String myPart = myTextParts[1];
System.out.println(myPart);
```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, when I use your xpath the _Elements_ inspector in developer tools does not find a xpath at all (0 of 0)

Comment: @K2017 Updated my answer, let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, but it still didn't work. I get a -_org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //font[contains(text(),'bouwdepotdeclaratie')]/text() (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)_

Comment: Check out my answer update and let me know the result.

Comment: This worked for me, it finally gave back the String that I that held the content of the email. Thanks. I only added the .getText() method at the end String myText: String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//font[contains(text(),'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]"))).getText();

Answer (score 0):

let me know did it help you or not,

If the current node is the font element, then something like this:

```
text()|span
```

otherwise you have to always combine with | the two complete XPath - the one for text and the one for span, e.g.:

```
font/text()|font/span
```

if the current node is just above font - or

```
//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/span|//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/text()
```

if starting from the root with some complex selection criteria.

If you have complex paths like the last one probably it is better to store a partial one in a variable - e.g. inside an XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="font" select="//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font"/>

. . . 

<xsl:for-each select="$font/span|$font/text()">
  . . . 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Another possibility is to do something like this:

```
//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/node()[name()='span' or name()='']
```

that works because name() returns an empty string for text() nodes - but I am not 100% sure that it works that way for all XPath processors, and it could match by mistake comment nodes.

Answer (score 0):

below xpath should work

```
//font[contains(.,'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]
or
//font[contains(text()[2],'Wij hebben uw bouwdepotdeclaratie verwerkt')]
```